# Regex expression that matches if the string contain only spaces?

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, formik, yup

I am using [formik](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik) with [yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup) to validate a form. In one input it passes if it contains only spaces, which is not valid for my use-case. So I went through Google to find some kind of regex so if the string only has spaces it would throw some message, but I didn't find anything.

```
nome: string()
      .min(3, '* Deve conter no mínimo 3 caracteres')
      .required('* Este campo é obrigatório')
      .matches(/[^\s*].*[^\s*]/g, '* This field cannot contain only blankspaces'),
```

The problem with this is that when it reaches 3 characters even with required yup condition the validation doesn't work, and matches with regex don't block the spaces. So far I managed a work-around with:
`nome: values.nome.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ')` But with the correct regex expression I can throw the error in real time.

Comment: Try `/^\S+$/` if you need to match a whole string that has no whitespace

Comment: Please provide an example input / output

Comment: Some kinda of : ```space.next === someCaracter ? valid : notValid``` logic and this "space next" would be looked by some regex express

Comment: Are you just making sure that the field does not contany any white space? In this case why not simply matchin for \s+ ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it worked if the whole string has no whitespace but if I wanna some kinda of example: fullname= Alex martines ?

Comment: Try `/^(?!\s+$).*/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It worked! Thank you so much, how can I vote for your comment for the right answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use

```js
/^(?!\s+$).*/
/^(?!\s+$)/
/^\s*\S.*$/
/^\s*\S[^]*$/
/^\s*\S[\s\S]*$/
```

The first two regexps will match any string that is not equal to 1 or more whitespaces.

The last third, fourth and fifth match a string that contains at least one non-whitespace char.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oyt27L/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!\s+$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are 1 or more whitespaces and end of string immediately to the right of the current location
- `.*` - 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\s*\S.*` - zero or more whitespaces, a non-whitespace, and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars
- `\s*\S[^]*` / `\s*\S[\s\S]*` - same as above but any chars including line breaks can appear after the non-whitespace char
- `$` - end of string

Comment: Thanks a lot! Perfect answer

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to match in case any white space is present please try:

```
nome: string()
      .min(3, '* Deve conter no mínimo 3 caracteres')
      .required('* Este campo é obrigatório')
      .matches(/^(\S+$)/g, '* This field cannot contain only blankspaces'),
```

Comment: Sorry, i mistook the error message, if the field has only white spaces then its not valid

Comment: ```.matches(/^(\S+$)/, '* This field cannot contain only blankspaces') ``` This worked for me, thanks!

Comment: I am glad it worked for you :) Please don't forget to upvote the answer and / or choose it as final answer.

Answer (score 1):

`.matches(/^(\S+$)/, '* This field cannot contain only blankspaces')` worked for me as well.

Mark the capital **S** but not the small **s**